# Keyboard repetition rate and delay are being reset on external keyboard plugin

Tags: usb, 20.04, keyboard, settings

Whenever I plug in an external USB keyboard into my ThinkPad T470s (or dock) running Ubuntu 20.04 with Gnome 3.36.3 and X11, the keyboard preferences key repetition rate and delay are automatically reset to the defaults, which are really slow. This is really annoying, since I have to readjust it manually in the settings every time I plug in my laptop.

I am aware that there is a similar question [Keyboard repeat/delay is reset when plugging in usb keyboard in Ubuntu 12.10 xfce](https://askubuntu.com/questions/261559/keyboard-repeat-delay-is-reset-when-plugging-in-usb-keyboard-in-ubuntu-12-10-xfc), but it is really old and the problem seems to not only affect xfce and it does not have a real solution.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer but might be a workaround.

From this article, you can set any keyboard delay/repetition from a terminal command and it can be registered as an alias or a shortcut.
`xset r rate 500 33`
The first digit is delay in milliseconds and second digit is repeats/sec.
In easy words, this gives the key starts to repeat after holding down a half second and 33 times per seconds.

Use of Keyboard Shortcuts on the System settings.

For example, you want to set <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>

[image: KBD repeat]

[image: register]

Every time you press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> the keyboard delay/repetition reset to the value, right away.

---

There is a trustworthy answer for this question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85504/setting-repeat-rate-of-usb-keyboard-automatically

I am not sure this works for your laptop.